# Hazelcast TransactionalQueue

Tags: queue, hazelcast, transactional

I am trying to use Hazelcast TransactionalQueue. 
I have 2 server instances running which polls a queue in a transaction, a simple client which offers items to the queue, if one of the servers dies after poll of an item, the item is lost and not available in the other server. Below is my code. I start 2 instances of the TestServer and then execute TestClient. Appreciate any pointers/help on what I am missing. Thanks

```
import java.util.Properties
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.{lang, util}

import com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient
import com.hazelcast.client.config.ClientConfig
import com.hazelcast.client.config.ClientConnectionStrategyConfig.ReconnectMode
import com.hazelcast.client.util.ClientStateListener
import com.hazelcast.config.{Config, QueueConfig, QueueStoreConfig}
import com.hazelcast.core.{Hazelcast, QueueStore, QueueStoreFactory}
import com.hazelcast.transaction.TransactionOptions

object TestServer {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val hazelcastServer = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(new Config())
    val hazelcastServerConfig = hazelcastServer.getConfig

    if (!hazelcastServerConfig.getQueueConfigs.containsKey("test")) {
      val qConfig = new QueueConfig("test")
      hazelcastServerConfig.addQueueConfig(qConfig)
    }

    // Creating HazelcastClient
    val hazelcastConfig = new ClientConfig()
    hazelcastConfig.getConnectionStrategyConfig.setAsyncStart(true).setReconnectMode(ReconnectMode.ASYNC)
    hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig.setConnectionAttemptLimit(0)
    val clientStateListener = new ClientStateListener(hazelcastConfig)
    val hazelcastClient = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(hazelcastConfig)

    while (!clientStateListener.isConnected) {
      println("waiting for connection to hazelcast server")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }

    while (true) {

      val context = hazelcastClient.newTransactionContext(new TransactionOptions().setTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
      context.beginTransaction()

      try {
        println("polling ...")
        val item = context.getQueue[String]("test").poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        println(item)
        // exit before commit
        if (item != null) {
          System.exit(1)
        }
        context.commitTransaction()
      } catch {
        case t: Throwable =>
          context.rollbackTransaction()
          throw t
      }
    }

  }
}


object TestClient {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Creating HazelcastClient
    val hazelcastConfig = new ClientConfig()
    hazelcastConfig.getConnectionStrategyConfig.setAsyncStart(true).setReconnectMode(ReconnectMode.ASYNC)
    hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig.setConnectionAttemptLimit(0)
    val clientStateListener = new ClientStateListener(hazelcastConfig)
    val hazelcastClient = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(hazelcastConfig)

    while (!clientStateListener.isConnected) {
      println("waiting for connection to hazelcast server")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
    hazelcastClient.getQueue[String]("test").offer(System.currentTimeMillis().toString)

    hazelcastClient.shutdown()
  }
}
```

Logs from Server instance 1 (item "1532569242798" is polled and exits out of JVM)

```
...
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:08 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Backpressure is disabled
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:08 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InboundResponseHandlerSupplier
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Running with 2 response threads
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:08 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Creating MulticastJoiner
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:09 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Starting 8 partition threads and 5 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:09 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:09 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] [10.246.242.50]:5701 is STARTING
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Cluster version set to 3.10
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] 

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
  Member [10.246.242.50]:5701 - fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b this
]

Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] [10.246.242.50]:5701 is STARTED
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] HazelcastClient 3.10.3 (20180718 - fec4eef) is STARTING
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientInvocationService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Running with 2 response threads
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] HazelcastClient 3.10.3 (20180718 - fec4eef) is STARTED
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Trying to connect to [127.0.0.1]:5701 as owner member
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpAcceptor
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Accepting socket connection from /127.0.0.1:58864
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Established socket connection between /127.0.0.1:5701 and /127.0.0.1:58864
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AuthenticationMessageTask
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Received auth from Connection[id=1, /127.0.0.1:5701->/127.0.0.1:58864, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT], successfully authenticated, principal: ClientPrincipal{uuid='d7d2c3c6-b46b-4daf-b3f9-c0acb5b088c0', ownerUuid='fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b'}, owner connection: true, client version: 3.10.3
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Setting ClientConnection{alive=true, connectionId=1, channel=NioChannel{/127.0.0.1:58864->/127.0.0.1:5701}, remoteEndpoint=[10.246.242.50]:5701, lastReadTime=2018-07-25 18:40:11.298, lastWriteTime=2018-07-25 18:40:11.284, closedTime=never, lastHeartbeatRequested=never, lastHeartbeatReceived=never, connected server version=3.10.3} as owner with principal ClientPrincipal{uuid='d7d2c3c6-b46b-4daf-b3f9-c0acb5b088c0', ownerUuid='fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b'}
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Authenticated with server [10.246.242.50]:5701, server version:3.10.3 Local address: /127.0.0.1:58864
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.PartitionStateManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Initializing cluster partition table arrangement...
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientMembershipListener
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] 

Members [1] {
  Member [10.246.242.50]:5701 - fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b
}

Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] HazelcastClient 3.10.3 (20180718 - fec4eef) is CLIENT_CONNECTED
waiting for connection to hazelcast server
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpAcceptor
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Accepting socket connection from /10.246.242.50:58865
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Established socket connection between /10.246.242.50:5701 and /10.246.242.50:58865
polling ...
loadAllKeys
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:17 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] 

Members {size:2, ver:2} [
  Member [10.246.242.50]:5701 - fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b this
  Member [10.246.242.50]:5702 - 4bf9f81c-88c5-419f-95af-8e97076bc69a
]

Jul 25, 2018 6:40:17 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientMembershipListener
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] 

Members [2] {
  Member [10.246.242.50]:5701 - fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b
  Member [10.246.242.50]:5702 - 4bf9f81c-88c5-419f-95af-8e97076bc69a
}

Jul 25, 2018 6:40:17 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Authenticated with server [10.246.242.50]:5702, server version:3.10.3 Local address: /10.246.242.50:58873
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:17 PM com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.MigrationManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Re-partitioning cluster data... Migration queue size: 271
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpAcceptor
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Accepting socket connection from /127.0.0.1:58876
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Established socket connection between /127.0.0.1:5701 and /127.0.0.1:58876
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AuthenticationMessageTask
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Received auth from Connection[id=3, /127.0.0.1:5701->/127.0.0.1:58876, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT], successfully authenticated, principal: ClientPrincipal{uuid='0f056275-c60f-446a-9f0d-448f39002540', ownerUuid='fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b'}, owner connection: true, client version: 3.10.3
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:19 PM com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.MigrationThread
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] All migration tasks have been completed, queues are empty.
null
polling ...
null
polling ...
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:41 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpAcceptor
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Accepting socket connection from /127.0.0.1:58903
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:41 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Established socket connection between /127.0.0.1:5701 and /127.0.0.1:58903
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:41 PM com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AuthenticationMessageTask
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Received auth from Connection[id=4, /127.0.0.1:5701->/127.0.0.1:58903, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT], successfully authenticated, principal: ClientPrincipal{uuid='e0bc9b95-39cf-47ed-8f01-b4cb14893c33', ownerUuid='fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b'}, owner connection: true, client version: 3.10.3
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Connection[id=4, /127.0.0.1:5701->/127.0.0.1:58903, endpoint=[127.0.0.1]:58903, alive=false, type=JAVA_CLIENT] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5701 [dev] [3.10.3] Running shutdown hook... Current state: ACTIVE
1532569242798

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Logs from Server instance 2.
I was expecting item "1532569242798" to be polled as commitTransaction() was never called from server 1

```
...
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:10 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Backpressure is disabled
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:10 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InboundResponseHandlerSupplier
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Running with 2 response threads
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Creating MulticastJoiner
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Starting 8 partition threads and 5 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] [10.246.242.50]:5702 is STARTING
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Trying to join to discovered node: [10.246.242.50]:5701
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Connecting to /10.246.242.50:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:11 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Established socket connection between /10.246.242.50:58865 and /10.246.242.50:5701
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:17 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpAcceptor
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Accepting socket connection from /10.246.242.50:58873
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:17 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Established socket connection between /10.246.242.50:5702 and /10.246.242.50:58873
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:17 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Cluster version set to 3.10
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:17 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] 

Members {size:2, ver:2} [
    Member [10.246.242.50]:5701 - fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b
    Member [10.246.242.50]:5702 - 4bf9f81c-88c5-419f-95af-8e97076bc69a this
]

Jul 25, 2018 6:40:17 PM com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AuthenticationMessageTask
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Received auth from Connection[id=2, /10.246.242.50:5702->/10.246.242.50:58873, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT], successfully authenticated, principal: ClientPrincipal{uuid='d7d2c3c6-b46b-4daf-b3f9-c0acb5b088c0', ownerUuid='fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b'}, owner connection: false, client version: 3.10.3
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] [10.246.242.50]:5702 is STARTED
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] HazelcastClient 3.10.3 (20180718 - fec4eef) is STARTING
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientInvocationService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Running with 2 response threads
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] HazelcastClient 3.10.3 (20180718 - fec4eef) is STARTED
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Trying to connect to [127.0.0.1]:5701 as owner member
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Setting ClientConnection{alive=true, connectionId=1, channel=NioChannel{/127.0.0.1:58876->/127.0.0.1:5701}, remoteEndpoint=[10.246.242.50]:5701, lastReadTime=2018-07-25 18:40:18.871, lastWriteTime=2018-07-25 18:40:18.867, closedTime=never, lastHeartbeatRequested=never, lastHeartbeatReceived=never, connected server version=3.10.3} as owner with principal ClientPrincipal{uuid='0f056275-c60f-446a-9f0d-448f39002540', ownerUuid='fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b'}
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Authenticated with server [10.246.242.50]:5701, server version:3.10.3 Local address: /127.0.0.1:58876
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientMembershipListener
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] 

Members [2] {
    Member [10.246.242.50]:5701 - fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b
    Member [10.246.242.50]:5702 - 4bf9f81c-88c5-419f-95af-8e97076bc69a
}

Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] HazelcastClient 3.10.3 (20180718 - fec4eef) is CLIENT_CONNECTED
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpAcceptor
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Accepting socket connection from /10.246.242.50:58877
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Established socket connection between /10.246.242.50:5702 and /10.246.242.50:58877
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AuthenticationMessageTask
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Received auth from Connection[id=3, /10.246.242.50:5702->/10.246.242.50:58877, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT], successfully authenticated, principal: ClientPrincipal{uuid='0f056275-c60f-446a-9f0d-448f39002540', ownerUuid='fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b'}, owner connection: false, client version: 3.10.3
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:18 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Authenticated with server [10.246.242.50]:5702, server version:3.10.3 Local address: /10.246.242.50:58877
polling ...
null
polling ...
null
polling ...
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpAcceptor
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Accepting socket connection from /10.246.242.50:58905
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Established socket connection between /10.246.242.50:5702 and /10.246.242.50:58905
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AuthenticationMessageTask
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Received auth from Connection[id=4, /10.246.242.50:5702->/10.246.242.50:58905, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT], successfully authenticated, principal: ClientPrincipal{uuid='e0bc9b95-39cf-47ed-8f01-b4cb14893c33', ownerUuid='fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b'}, owner connection: false, client version: 3.10.3
store
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Connection[id=4, /10.246.242.50:5702->/10.246.242.50:58905, endpoint=[10.246.242.50]:58905, alive=false, type=JAVA_CLIENT] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Connection[id=1, /10.246.242.50:58865->/10.246.242.50:5701, endpoint=[10.246.242.50]:5701, alive=false, type=MEMBER] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] ClientConnection{alive=false, connectionId=1, channel=NioChannel{/127.0.0.1:58876->/127.0.0.1:5701}, remoteEndpoint=[10.246.242.50]:5701, lastReadTime=2018-07-25 18:40:42.814, lastWriteTime=2018-07-25 18:40:38.897, closedTime=2018-07-25 18:40:42.814, lastHeartbeatRequested=2018-07-25 18:40:38.857, lastHeartbeatReceived=2018-07-25 18:40:38.858, connected server version=3.10.3} closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.client.ClientEndpointManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Destroying ClientEndpoint{connection=Connection[id=4, /10.246.242.50:5702->/10.246.242.50:58905, endpoint=[10.246.242.50]:58905, alive=false, type=JAVA_CLIENT], principal='ClientPrincipal{uuid='e0bc9b95-39cf-47ed-8f01-b4cb14893c33', ownerUuid='fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b'}, ownerConnection=false, authenticated=true, clientVersion=3.10.3, creationTime=1532569242626, latest statistics=null}
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Connecting to /10.246.242.50:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Removed connection to endpoint: [10.246.242.50]:5701, connection: ClientConnection{alive=false, connectionId=1, channel=NioChannel{/127.0.0.1:58876->/127.0.0.1:5701}, remoteEndpoint=[10.246.242.50]:5701, lastReadTime=2018-07-25 18:40:42.814, lastWriteTime=2018-07-25 18:40:38.897, closedTime=2018-07-25 18:40:42.814, lastHeartbeatRequested=2018-07-25 18:40:38.857, lastHeartbeatReceived=2018-07-25 18:40:38.858, connected server version=3.10.3}
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Could not connect to: /10.246.242.50:5701. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /10.246.242.50:5701]
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] HazelcastClient 3.10.3 (20180718 - fec4eef) is CLIENT_DISCONNECTED
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Trying to connect to [10.246.242.50]:5702 as owner member
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Connecting to /10.246.242.50:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Could not connect to: /10.246.242.50:5701. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /10.246.242.50:5701]
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Connecting to /10.246.242.50:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:42 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
.......
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Could not connect to: /10.246.242.50:5701. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /10.246.242.50:5701]
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionErrorHandler
WARNING: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Removing connection to endpoint [10.246.242.50]:5701 Cause => java.net.SocketException {Connection refused to address /10.246.242.50:5701}, Error-Count: 5
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MembershipManager
WARNING: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Member [10.246.242.50]:5701 - fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b is suspected to be dead for reason: No connection
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MembershipManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Starting mastership claim process...
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MembershipManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Local MembersView{version=2, members=[MemberInfo{address=[10.246.242.50]:5701, uuid=fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b, liteMember=false, memberListJoinVersion=1}, MemberInfo{address=[10.246.242.50]:5702, uuid=4bf9f81c-88c5-419f-95af-8e97076bc69a, liteMember=false, memberListJoinVersion=2}]} with suspected members: [[10.246.242.50]:5701] and initial addresses to ask: []
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Connecting to /10.246.242.50:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Could not connect to: /10.246.242.50:5701. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /10.246.242.50:5701]
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] 

Members {size:1, ver:3} [
    Member [10.246.242.50]:5702 - 4bf9f81c-88c5-419f-95af-8e97076bc69a this
]

Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MembershipManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Mastership is claimed with: MembersView{version=3, members=[MemberInfo{address=[10.246.242.50]:5702, uuid=4bf9f81c-88c5-419f-95af-8e97076bc69a, liteMember=false, memberListJoinVersion=2}]}
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.internal.partition.InternalPartitionService
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Fetching most recent partition table! my version: 678
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.internal.partition.InternalPartitionService
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Most recent partition table version: 678
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.transaction.TransactionManagerService
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Committing/rolling-back live transactions of [10.246.242.50]:5701, UUID: fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.MigrationManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Partition balance is ok, no need to re-partition cluster data... 
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Connection[id=2, /10.246.242.50:5702->/10.246.242.50:58873, endpoint=[10.246.242.50]:58873, alive=false, type=JAVA_CLIENT] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.client.ClientEndpointManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Destroying ClientEndpoint{connection=Connection[id=2, /10.246.242.50:5702->/10.246.242.50:58873, endpoint=[10.246.242.50]:58873, alive=false, type=JAVA_CLIENT], principal='ClientPrincipal{uuid='d7d2c3c6-b46b-4daf-b3f9-c0acb5b088c0', ownerUuid='fbee8d35-2b48-471b-a474-5dc2c5004a5b'}, ownerConnection=false, authenticated=true, clientVersion=3.10.3, creationTime=1532569217769, latest statistics=null}
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AuthenticationMessageTask
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Received auth from Connection[id=3, /10.246.242.50:5702->/10.246.242.50:58877, endpoint=[10.246.242.50]:58877, alive=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT], successfully authenticated, principal: ClientPrincipal{uuid='0f056275-c60f-446a-9f0d-448f39002540', ownerUuid='4bf9f81c-88c5-419f-95af-8e97076bc69a'}, owner connection: true, client version: 3.10.3
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AuthenticationMessageTask
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Received auth from Connection[id=2, /10.246.242.50:5702->/10.246.242.50:58873, endpoint=[10.246.242.50]:58873, alive=false, type=JAVA_CLIENT], successfully authenticated, principal: ClientPrincipal{uuid='d7d2c3c6-b46b-4daf-b3f9-c0acb5b088c0', ownerUuid='4bf9f81c-88c5-419f-95af-8e97076bc69a'}, owner connection: true, client version: 3.10.3
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Setting ClientConnection{alive=true, connectionId=2, channel=NioChannel{/10.246.242.50:58877->/10.246.242.50:5702}, remoteEndpoint=[10.246.242.50]:5702, lastReadTime=2018-07-25 18:40:43.640, lastWriteTime=2018-07-25 18:40:42.820, closedTime=never, lastHeartbeatRequested=2018-07-25 18:40:38.858, lastHeartbeatReceived=2018-07-25 18:40:38.858, connected server version=3.10.3} as owner with principal ClientPrincipal{uuid='0f056275-c60f-446a-9f0d-448f39002540', ownerUuid='4bf9f81c-88c5-419f-95af-8e97076bc69a'}
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] Authenticated with server [10.246.242.50]:5702, server version:3.10.3 Local address: /10.246.242.50:58877
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientMembershipListener
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] 

Members [1] {
    Member [10.246.242.50]:5702 - 4bf9f81c-88c5-419f-95af-8e97076bc69a
}

Jul 25, 2018 6:40:43 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.10.3] HazelcastClient 3.10.3 (20180718 - fec4eef) is CLIENT_CONNECTED
null
polling ...
Jul 25, 2018 6:40:51 PM com.hazelcast.client.ClientEndpointManager
INFO: [10.246.242.50]:5702 [dev] [3.10.3] Destroying ClientEndpoint{connection=Connection[id=2, /10.246.242.50:5702->/10.246.242.50:58873, endpoint=[10.246.242.50]:58873, alive=false, type=JAVA_CLIENT], principal='ClientPrincipal{uuid='d7d2c3c6-b46b-4daf-b3f9-c0acb5b088c0', ownerUuid='4bf9f81c-88c5-419f-95af-8e97076bc69a'}, ownerConnection=true, authenticated=true, clientVersion=3.10.3, creationTime=1532569217769, latest statistics=null}
null
polling ...
null
polling ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`queue.poll()` removes and returns to the head of the queue. Once the item has been consumed/removed and the server dies then loosing that item is expected - general behaviour of Queue. If you want the item to remain in cluster than use `queue.peek()` and enable queue backup.

Comment: Since I am creating a TransactionalQueue, if the transaction is not committed after poll(), should the item not go back to the queue?
When I do rollbackTransaction(), the item is back in the queue, but that is not happening if the jvm crashes before commit

Comment: For Queue transactions, offered/polled objects are copied within the owner member so that they can be rolled back when prompted, which is why you see objects going back in the queue on rollbackTransaction(). So since the objects are polled, means out of the queue and the server crashes before the txn could be rolled back, the objects have no way to make it to back to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but since you're using Scala, the [Hazelcast Scala API](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-scala) allows you to write the while loop like this:

```
import com.hazelcast.Scala._

// ...

while (true) {
  client.transaction(timeout = 20.seconds) { context =>
    // transactional code, commit/rollback happens automatically
  }
}
```

See: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-scala/wiki/Transactions